# SQL Pivot String Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a tables in SQL Server: Product

**Product Table**:

```
ImageID  ProductID  
-------  ---------- 
1           P1
1           P2             
1           P3             
2           S1
2           S2
2           S3
3           M1
```

This is the output that I need:

```
ImageID  Product1ID     Product2ID      Product3ID
----------- ---------- ----------    ----------
1           P1             P2           P3
2           S1             S2           S3
3           M1             null         null
```

An ImageID can have maximum 3 ProductID
It is not necessary that all ImageID will have 3 products [eg. ImageID=3]

```
SELECT ImageID, [Product1ID], [Product2ID], [Product3ID]
FROM    
(  
        SELECT ImageID,  ProductID
        FROM ProductTable
) AS P
PIVOT 
(  
    max( ImageID) 
    FOR ProductID IN ([Product1ID], [Product2ID], [Product3ID])
) AS  PVT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your were very close, you just needed to incorporate `Row_Number()`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        Select ImageID
              ,Item = concat('Product',row_number() over (partition by ImageID order by ProductID),'ID') 
              ,ProductID
         From ProductTable
       ) src
Pivot (max(ProductID) for Item in ([Product1ID], [Product2ID], [Product3ID])) pvt
```

Answer (score 4):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ImageID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN ProductID END) as Product1ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN ProductID END) as Product2ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN ProductID END) as Product3ID
FROM (SELET pt.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ImageId ORDER BY ProductID) as seqnum
      FROM ProductTable
     ) P
GROUP BY ImageID;
```

The key idea, though, is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate the products.